# SQL Pivot multiple columns without forcing aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I need to pivot out some denormalized data but it repeats so I need it to pivot out the columns and then return multiple rows.

I have a table like this

```
INSERT #TheTable
VALUES 
        ('StockCode'    ,'a'),
        ('Warehouse'    ,'b'),
        ('TrnYear'  ,'c'),
        ('TrnMonth' ,'d'),
        ('EntryDate'    ,'e'),
        ('TrnTime'  ,'f'),
        ('StockCode'    ,'1'),
        ('Warehouse'    ,'2'),
        ('TrnYear'  ,'3'),
        ('TrnMonth' ,'4'),
        ('EntryDate'    ,'5'),
        ('TrnTime'  ,'6')
```

But when I pivot it only returns one row:

```
SELECT  StockCode,
        Warehouse,
        TrnYear,
        TrnMonth,
        TrnTime,
        EntryDate        
FROM    #TheTable AS src 
PIVOT   (MAX(column_value)
         FOR COLUMN_NAME in ([TrnYear], [TrnMonth], [EntryDate], [TrnTime], [StockCode], [Warehouse])) AS piv
```

Result:

```
StockCode   Warehouse   TrnYear TrnMonth    TrnTime EntryDate   
-------------------------------------------------------------   
a           b           c       d           f       e
```

But I need it to return

```
StockCode   Warehouse   TrnYear TrnMonth    TrnTime EntryDate   
-------------------------------------------------------------   
a           b           c       d           f       e           
1           2           3       4           5       6
```

Comment: Without a column that defines group it does not make sense and tables are not ordered. [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9712e09026e72bd9f1d846a3bded58d)

Why we have `a,b,c,d,f,e` and not `a,2,c,4,f,g` in the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed a row_number per every group of column names. So the below worked

```
SELECT DISTINCT TrnYear,
                TrnMonth,
                EntryDate,
                TrnTime,
                StockCode,
                Warehouse
FROM
  (SELECT  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dw_view_change_event_nr) - 1) / 6 + 1 AS rn,
          COLUMN_NAME ,
         column_value
   FROM
     #TheTable AS tmp) AS src PIVOT (MAX(column_value)
                                                          FOR COLUMN_NAME in ([TrnYear], [TrnMonth], [EntryDate], [TrnTime], [StockCode], [Warehouse])) AS piv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions first, then conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when column_name = 'StockCode' then column_value end) StockCode,
    max(case when column_name = 'Warehouse' then column_value end) Warehouse,
    max(case when column_name = 'TrnYear'   then column_value end) TrnYear,
    max(case when column_name = 'TrnMonth'  then column_value end) TrnMonth,
    max(case when column_name = 'TrnTime'   then column_value end) TrnTime,
    max(case when column_name = 'EntryDate' then column_value end) EntryDate
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by column_name order by column_value) rn
    from #TheTable t
) t
group by rn
```

Comment: Thanks. That would work but I need it to be dynamic. I've just figured it out so I'll post the solution below and still vote your solution up

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function :

```
SELECT *
  FROM
 (
  SELECT column_name, column_value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY column_value) AS rn
    FROM #TheTable 
 ) q
PIVOT   
 ( MAX(column_value)
   FOR column_name in ([TrnYear], [TrnMonth], [EntryDate], [TrnTime], [StockCode], [Warehouse])
 ) AS piv
```

or more dynamically, use :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name,',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
                        FROM [#TheTable] ) q );

SET  @query = 
 N'SELECT *  
     FROM
     (
      SELECT column_name, column_value,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY [column_name] ORDER BY [column_value]) AS rn
        FROM [#TheTable]
      ) f
    PIVOT 
    (
     MAX([column_value]) FOR [column_name] IN (' + @cols + N')
    ) AS piv '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3751426bf7b403b4f3b2a47e21c1b14d)</kbd>